# What does "Free" means in Heap monitoring screen when running Android app on emulator (eclipse)?

Tags: java, android, memory

When I run my app on Android emulator, the app will load a content of a (large) text file. There's no problem until now, but when I look at the stats, I am confused about what the "free" type means.

Does it mean my app has allocated big objects and they are unused now? Or it just says that it's the free memory of the device?

[image]

Regard

p.s: I'm new to Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Free" means the memory is allocated to the JVM as heap memory but not being used by live objects at the moment, i.e. it has either never been used or (much more likey) was previously used by objects that have since been garbage collected.

Answer (score -1):

It shows the remaining amount of memory in your simulator's allocation for the Heap.

Comment: it's a Emulator not simulator while you are developing on Android, :)